# Is it possible to get all data in a csv file in a step spring batch(version 4.0.1)?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch  that reads each line at a time in a step as follows:

```
@Bean("step2")
public Step fileEmployeeDetailsValidationStep() {
    LOGGER.debug("In fileBuyerDetailsValidationStep:  details Validation.");
    StepBuilder stepBuilder = stepBuilderFactory.get(Flow.STEP2.toString());
    SimpleStepBuilder<EmployeeDetailsDto, ImportErrorWrapperList> simpleStepBuilder = stepBuilder.<EmployeeDetailsDto, ImportErrorWrapperList>chunk(20000);
    simpleStepBuilder.reader(csvItemReader.csvFileEmployeeFileItemReader(null));
    simpleStepBuilder.processor(employeeDetailsValidatorProcessor());
    simpleStepBuilder.writer(detailErrorWriter());
    simpleStepBuilder.allowStartIfComplete(true);
    return simpleStepBuilder.build();
}
```

The file contains an Employer and a list of records (Employees) as follows:

Employer
id, name, surname
Employee
id, name, surname

Instead of reading each line at a time is it possible to get all the records of employee information at once in step 2?

Basically the reason i need a list is to build a list of employee and pass it to a web service in that step.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can user Tasklet and have the item reader bean inside that

```
@Bean
  protected Step readLines() {
        return steps
          .get("readLines")
          .tasklet(linesReader())
          .build();
    }
```

and

```
public class LinesReader implements Tasklet {
    // ...
}
```